# Notify admin if a user is locked out in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Currently, I have thee statuses: `A` for `Active`, `D` for `Disabled`, and `L` for `Locked`. I already set the `$maxAttempts = 3`, `$decayMinutes = 10` and added the code to the `LoginController` so that only active users can log in.

```php
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 
        'password', 'site_id'), ['status' => 'A']);
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to automatically change the status from `Active` to `Locked` after the user logs in with an incorrect password three times continuously. Currently, the following is the view.

[image]

Comment: take a column in user table called 'status' , when user get locked up...update the status field to 0 and in the view show it as a button like locked Up.. When the amin click in this button then update the status 1 and then user can login again. Perhaps it will get the idea how to do it

Comment: welcome try and let me know the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the lockout happens Laravel fires an Illuminte\Auth\Events\Lockout event. As we know, we can easily set up a listener for this event and handle any logic we want. You can simple make a listener with the `php artisan make:listener UserLockedOut` command. Then bind the listener to the event in the event service provider.

Then in the handle method of your listener you can write you code to notify admin and update status of user in database table column, of course if you want to track status of user then simple make a column in database table and tweak it in listeners handle method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\User;
use App\Notifications\LockedOut;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;

class UserLockedOut
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Lockout $event)
    {
        if ($user = User::where('email', 'admin@admin.com')->first()) {
            $user->notify(new LockedOut);
        }

        // code to update the database table column e.g
          
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'll try to do it

Comment: @Chxk welcome, if it helped you mark it as accepted answer so others can also take advantage of it.If you have any query implementing it then let me know.